# java compiler throwing useless error messages

Tags: java, compiler-errors

i do not understand where these errors are coming from, i've checked and checked again and i don't seem to be missing any semi-colons.

```
exceptions1.java:8: error: ';' expected
    boolean isPrime(int n) {
                   ^
exceptions1.java:8: error: ';' expected
    boolean isPrime(int n) {
                         ^
2 errors
```

and here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class exceptions1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Check if number is prime: ");

        boolean isPrime(int n) {
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        System.out.println(isPrime(input.nextInt()));
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant have methods inside methods.

Comment: Yeah, those are useless. I mean the code doesn't compile but the errors are definitely useless.

Comment: Something that is good to learn about java error messages is that they shouldn't be interpreted literally. Another common message that throws new programmers is the "; not found" when in fact you need an extra closing parentheses.

Comment: go to hell boris you twocker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java doesnt support nested methods. Move `isPrime` out of the `main` method